# From a plugin how can I override a different plugin template file.?

Tags: magento2, module, template

I'm really new to Magento.

How can I override a modules templates files from another module ?

I have this file:

> `/app/code/Amasty/Shopby/view/frontend/templates/layer/filter/swatch/default.phtml`

How can I override that file from my own module ?

Thanks.

---

Based on the comments below:

this is the file I'm trying to override:

`app/code/Amasty/Shopby/Block/Navigation/FilterRenderer.php`

I have made:

`app/code/Kodal/BindingShape/Plugin/FilterRenderer.php`

I have added a DI file:

`<type name="Amasty\Shopby\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer">
        <plugin name="Kodal_BindingShapePlugin" 
        type="Kodal\BindingShape\Plugin\FilterRenderer"/>
</type>`

in my file there is a method:

`public function afterGetTemplateByFilterSetting(Amasty\ShopbyBase\Api\Data\FilterSettingInterface $filterSetting)
    {
        die('==> we are here');
    }`

But nothing happens, what am I missing ?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Option 1:
You can use an `after` plugin for the method `getTemplate` on the blocks that use  that template.

Something like

```
public function afterGetTemplate(BlockClassNameHere $subject, $template)
{
     return 'Your own template';
}
```

Upside is that the template will be part of your module. Disabling your module will revert to the original template.
Downside is that you may need to create multiple plugins if different blocks use this template and they don't have a common ancestor class.

Option 2:
Copy the exact template in your theme and modify it as you want.
This way you don't care which block class uses it, it will change everywhere, but you the downside is that the new template will not be part of your module. In case you disable your module, the template will still be used.